# When using opencv-python for pyautogui the module requires the numpy module but it is already downloaded all within a virtual environment

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyautogui

I am currently making use of PyautoGUI to automate some clicks. Within the process I would need to download the opencv-python module via

`pip install opencv-python`

After doing so I made use of the confidence parameter for a locate function in this case 'locateOnScreen()' which requires opencv library. The problem occurs when running my code and I receive a warning rather than an error in:

`OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package. Install it via command: pip install numpy`

The problem is that when I run it is already downloaded:

`pip show numpy`

Output:

`Name: numpy  Version: 1.25.1 Summary: Fundamental package for array computing in Python  Home-page: https://www.numpy.org  Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.  Author-email:  License: BSD-3-Clause  Location: /Users/AC_Home/Documents/TalentChamCRM/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages  Requires:  Required-by: opencv-python`

I am currently using a virtual environment and do not know if this is what is causing me problems.

The second problem is when using the confidence parameter in the locate function I receive an error as the following:

Output:

`raise NotImplementedError('The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.') NotImplementedError: The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.`

When I run the command to view the installed version I get

`pip show opencv-python`

Output:
`Name: opencv-python Version: 4.8.0.74 Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings. Home-page: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python Author: Author-email: License: Apache 2.0 Location: /Users/AC_Home/Documents/TalentChamCRM/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages Requires: numpy, numpy, numpy Required-by:`

I have tried using the CLI and pip to uninstall numpy and reinstall but the same error appears I have also tried manually removing the file but it did not work. I have been at this problem for around a day and have tried many possible solutions online but none work for me.

Answer (score 0):

First,check if you have activated your virtual environment or not, second  it could be due to pip version being too old being too old,try using ,`pip install --upgrade pip`.